# Differentiable functions and tangent planes

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A curve $\gamma$ is the intersection of a cylinder $S= \{ (x,y,z)|x^2+y^2=2\} $ and a graph of a function $z=f(x,y)$ . In addition, the point $M(1,1,2) $ lies on this curve. $f(x,y)$ is differentiable everywhere and $\nabla f(1,1)= (1,2)$ .

Find the equation of the line tangent to the curve $C$ at $M$ .

My attempt:

All I know is that the equation for the plane tangent to $f$ at $(1,1,2)$ is:
$
z=x-1+2(y-1)+2 = x+2y-1 
$ 
and that I only need the direction of the tangent line to find it (I already have a point). I know that a normal to the plane is $(1,2,-1)$ .

WIll you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's sketch a parametric representation of $\gamma$:
$$\gamma(t)=\big(\sqrt2\cos t,\sqrt 2\sin t, f(\sqrt2\cos t, \sqrt 2\sin t)\big)$$

Then,
$$\gamma'(t)=\big(-\sqrt2\sin t,\sqrt 2\cos t,-\sqrt2\sin tf_x(\sqrt2\cos t,\sqrt 2\sin t)+\sqrt 2\cos t f_y(\sqrt 2\cos t,\sqrt 2\sin t)\big)$$

The curve $\gamma$ meets the point $(1,1,2)$ at $t=\pi/4$. The direction vector of the tangent line will be
$$\gamma'(\pi/4)=(-1,1,-f_x(1,1)+f_y(1,1))=(-1,1,1)$$